# Holder inequality of Schatten norm for p=q=2 and Hermitian operators

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, holder-inequality

I was reading some Linear Algebra contents and then I encountered this problem, I tried to prove this by using for example Holder inequality for Schatten norms, But I didn't succeed. The question is :

Show that for any Hermitian operators $M, \sigma \in \operatorname{Herm}(A),$ with $\sigma \geqslant 0,$ the following holds:
$$
\|\sqrt{\sigma} M \sqrt{\sigma}\|_{1} \leqslant\|M\|_{2}\|\sigma\|_{2}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when dealing with Schatten norms, which explicitly use singular values $\sigma_k$, it's a really bad idea to overload this and use $\sigma$ to denote a matrix, so I restate the problem as follows

for HPSD $B$, and Hermitian $M$ prove:
$\|B^\frac{1}{2} M B^\frac{1}{2} \|_{S_1} \leq\|M\|_{2}\|B\|_{S_2}$

Let $\Sigma_X$ denote a diagonal matrix containing the singular values of $X$ in order from largest to smallest.

**proof 1: (less machinery)**
$\|B^\frac{1}{2} M B^\frac{1}{2} \|_{S_1}$
$\leq \| M B \|_{S_1}$
$=\text{trace}\Big(U^*M B\Big)$
$\leq \text{trace}\Big(\Sigma_{U^*M}\Sigma_{B}\Big)$
$= \text{trace}\Big(\Sigma_{M}\Sigma_{B}\Big)$
$\leq \text{trace}\Big(\big(\Sigma_{M}\big)^2\Big)^\frac{1}{2}\cdot \text{trace}\Big(\big(\Sigma_{B}\big)^2\Big)^\frac{1}{2}$
$= \Big\Vert M\Big\Vert_{S_2}\cdot \Big\Vert B\Big\Vert_{S_2}$

where the inequalities are
*(i)* $B^\frac{1}{2} M B^\frac{1}{2}$ is Hermitian, hence Normal, so if we apply Schur Triangularization it is diagonal, with singular values given by the eigenvalues (and rescaled by a point on the unit circle as needed). On the other hand $M B$ has the same eigenvalues but in general is not normal, so it has a higher Schatten 1 norm.  To make this explicit, where $MB$ may be Schur triangularizated by $Q$ and with some optimally chosen unitary diagonal matrix $D$
$\sum_{k=1}^n \big\vert\lambda_k^{(MB)}\big\vert =\sum_{k=1}^n \big\vert\lambda_k^{(B^\frac{1}{2}MB^\frac{1}{2})}\big\vert  =\big\Vert B^\frac{1}{2} M B^\frac{1}{2}\big\Vert_{S_1}$  but by  von Neumann Trace Inequality
$\sum_{k=1}^n \big\vert\lambda_k^{(MB)}\big\vert =\text{trace}\Big(\big(QDQ^*\big)  M B\Big)\leq \text{trace}\Big(\Sigma_{QDQ^*} \Sigma_{M B}\Big)=\big\Vert  M B\big\Vert_{S_1}$

*(ii)* von Neumann Trace Inequality
*(iii)* Cauchy Schwarz

**proof 2: (more general)**
Now, by Polar decomposition we have $B^\frac{1}{2} M B^\frac{1}{2}=UP$

$\|B^\frac{1}{2} M B^\frac{1}{2} \|_{S_1}$
$=\text{trace}\Big(U^*B^\frac{1}{2} M B^\frac{1}{2}\Big)$
$\leq\text{trace}\Big(\Sigma_{U^*B^\frac{1}{2}} \Sigma_{M B^\frac{1}{2}}\Big)$
$=\text{trace}\Big(\Sigma_{B^\frac{1}{2}} \Sigma_{M B^\frac{1}{2}}\Big)$
$\leq\text{trace}\Big(\Sigma_{B^\frac{1}{2}} \Sigma_{M}\Sigma_{B^\frac{1}{2}}\Big)$
$=\text{trace}\Big(\Sigma_{M}\Sigma_{B^\frac{1}{2}}\Sigma_{B^\frac{1}{2}} \Big)$
$=\text{trace}\Big(\Sigma_{M}\Sigma_{B}\Big)$
$\leq \text{trace}\Big(\big(\Sigma_{M}\big)^2\Big)^\frac{1}{2}\cdot \text{trace}\Big(\big(\Sigma_{B}\big)^2\Big)^\frac{1}{2}$
$=\Big\Vert M\Big\Vert_{S_2}\cdot \Big\Vert B\Big\Vert_{S_2}$

where the inequalities are
*(i)* von Neumann Trace Inequality
*(ii)* the fact that $\Sigma_{XY} \preceq_w \Sigma_{X}\Sigma_{Y}$ with $\preceq_w$ denoting weak majorization
*(iii)* Cauchy-Schwarz

Notice that Hermicity of $M$ was not needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your useful and relative answer. But I have three questions. In proof 2:         1. why do we need polar decomposition?                                                                        2.how can you insert the U* in line 2 and why do we need that?                                                      3.how can we get the line 4 from line 3, I mean how do you omit U* from line 3 and then obtain line 4?

Comment: (1.) Polar Decomposition is useful, read: sufficient not necessary. (2.) $\text{trace}\Big(U^*B^\frac{1}{2} M B^\frac{1}{2}\Big) = \text{trace}\Big(P\Big)$ and $P\succeq 0$ so its trace gives sum of singular values  and $P$ has the same singular values as $\big(B^\frac{1}{2} M B^\frac{1}{2}\big)$  (3.)  $\Sigma_{U^*B^\frac{1}{2}} =\Sigma_{B^\frac{1}{2}}$   because multiplication by a unitary matrix doesn't change singular values.

Comment: Thank you so much dear friend. I'm sorry, but I have one more question. you wrote that "Hermicity of M was not needed", So I have two question, first where did we use the hermicity of B? And why does the question assume M is Hermitian, But you told me that it was not needed.? Thank you in advance

Comment: If you look carefully, Hermicity of $M$ was needed in the first proof.  The point is: by using more sophisticated machinery, we don't need this.  I don't have your text or even know what it is so I won't speculate on why the author set up the question this way.  As for $B$ -- suppose $B$ was not Hermitian (and in particular not normal) but it had a square root that we agreed on, then you'd still have the problem that $ \Sigma_{B}  \preceq_w \Sigma_{B^\frac{1}{2}}\Sigma_{B^\frac{1}{2}} $ which points 'the wrong way' though this is of course an equality when $B^\frac{1}{2}$ is Hermitian.

Comment: Dear friend. Today I was discussing with one of my friends about this question and he said that in this proof there is something wrong. In fact, he said that it is not true that the multiplication of a positive semi-definite matrix by a unitary matrix does not change singular values, And I couldn't convince him. You also said that $trace(U^* B^{1/2} M B^{1/2})=trace(P)$ and P>0, so its trace gives sum of singular values and P has the same singular value as $(B^{1/2} M B^{1/2})$. and He said it is not true too.

Comment: This isn't really the right way to address this.  Your friend is wrong and *you* should have been able to prove this to him.  I'd ask both of you to consider -- where do singular values of a square matrix $A$ come from?  They aren't magic.  A standard way of defining them is to take the eigenvalues of $A^* A$  and then square root them.  But if you multiply by unitary $U$,  then $(UA)^*(UA) = A^*U^*U A = A^*A$ so the singular values haven't changed.  This is why *you* need to learn the proofs.  The fact that singular values equal eigenvalues for HPSD matrices is implied by this as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear friend. I have one more question. Can we also say $Tr(U^*\sigma^{1/2}M\sigma^{1/2})=Tr(\sigma^{1/2}M\sigma^{1/2})$ ?